# Accessing the PHP Variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day to all of you Ma'am and Sir

I have a problem to my project (never mind the name of the project because it is for privately use and it is for security of the website).

The problem is I can not access or forward the PHP Variable value to the external javascript file.

this is the code in insert.php

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 ?>
<input type="text" id="code"/>
<button id="con_btn"/>Continue</button>
```

this is the code in insert_auth.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#con_btn").click(function(){
        var code = $("#code").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "post.php",
            data:{
                code:code,
                },
            success: function(data){
                $("#insertresult").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I just want to get the value of the $username from php file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should a **username** be private from the user?

Comment: the username is not private, the $username that you see in the php file is inserted previously from other php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it as you already have the POST value : `$_POST['username'];`. So, I'd suggest you to store this value as a hidden input field.

```
<?php $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // Store username in session ?>

<input type="text" id="code"/>
<button id="con_btn"/>Continue</button>
```

Now, in your JS, you can access this hidden field value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#con_btn").click(function(){
        var code = $("#code").val();
        var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"  // Read username from session
        $.ajax({
          /* Other code */
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not secured if you put it in the html, they can easily inspect element it. Is there any other possible solution? Anyways thank you very much for your solution sir.

Comment: Then I think you should try using sessions. That's the only possible way other than hidden input. But it certainly has its limitations.

Comment: Ok Sir Thank you very much :) I already tried the session but it is risky for me because of the user session expiration. But thank you for your solutions :)